# MYSQL Union Query with a count

Tags: mysql, count, union

I’m trying to combine results from a count statement with results from other criteria (multiple tables), and am beating my head against a wall. 
My skills are not strong in this area, and getting to this point has been interesting.  The last issue in this phase is that although I’m seeing the results I’m looking for, my UNION ALL isn’t combining the data.
You can see in the bottom table (RESULTS), that I'm getting multiple instances of the same system.  I realize that I’m calling the same count twice, and it’s probably correctly trying to show me both counts, but all of my efforts to change that have taken me to other problems.
Eventually, I would also like to add at least two more counts from additional tables as well, but hopefully that won’t be as challenging once this is past. (I am also trying to get data for "systemid" where the count doesn't apply, I only want it to return those items specifically related to the count where the count is one or more.  I've copied sample tables and code below.
Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Dave

#### TABLE1: SYSTEMS

```
+-----+-----------+-----------+----------------+  
| sid |   Name    | checkdate | MissingPatches |  
+-----+-----------+-----------+----------------+  
|  52 | WCLDC     |  20130623 |              2 |  
|  79 | WCLVS001  |         0 |              0 |  
| 112 | TAR201    |         0 |              3 |  
| 179 | DOX109N   |  20130603 |              0 |  
| 181 | DOX122T   |  20130520 |              0 |  
| 184 | DOX121T   |  20130411 |              0 |  
| 248 | ROW1767L  |  20130530 |              2 |  
| 251 | ROW1765L  |  20130528 |              1 |  
| 268 | GWR-LAP16 |  20130531 |              3 |  
| 278 | ROW1522L  |  20130420 |              1 |  
| 281 | ROW255L   |  20130509 |              1 |  
| 283 | GWR-LAP03 |  20130413 |              2 |  
| 313 | GMSRT     |  20130623 |              1 |  
| 334 | ROW1517L  |  20130523 |              1 |  
| 335 | ROW1792L  |         0 |              0 |  
| 339 | TEXCE-PC  |         0 |              0 |  
+-----+-----------+-----------+----------------+
```

---

#### TABLE2: PATCHES

╔═════╦══════════╦══════════╦═══════════╗
║ sid ║ PatchID  ║ Approved ║ Installed ║
╠═════╬══════════╬══════════╬═══════════╣
║  52 ║ a34236   ║        1 ║         0 ║
║  52 ║ b54656   ║        1 ║         0 ║
║ 112 ║ ds6456   ║        1 ║         0 ║
║ 112 ║ se4168   ║        1 ║         0 ║
║ 112 ║ f46466   ║        1 ║         0 ║
║ 248 ║ t44541   ║        1 ║         0 ║
║ 248 ║ uyt446   ║        1 ║         0 ║
║ 251 ║ gfd841   ║        1 ║         0 ║
║ 268 ║ 54dtyd   ║        1 ║         0 ║
║ 268 ║ dg4495   ║        1 ║         0 ║
║ 268 ║ dg4444   ║        1 ║         0 ║
║ 278 ║ jhr652   ║        1 ║         0 ║
║ 281 ║ h46831   ║        1 ║         0 ║
║ 283 ║ 54fghf   ║        1 ║         0 ║
║ 283 ║ 46fhtj   ║        1 ║         0 ║
║ 313 ║ s44971   ║        1 ║         0 ║
║ 334 ║ et4796   ║        1 ║         0 ║
║ 339 ║ TEXCE-PC ║        0 ║         0 ║
╚═════╩══════════╩══════════╩═══════════╝

---

#### CODE:

```
SELECT
  systems.sid, systems.Name, systems.checkdate,
  SUM(0) as MissingPatches
FROM (
  patches LEFT JOIN Systems
  ON Systems.Sid = patches.Sid
)
WHERE (
  STR_TO_DATE(systems.checkdate, '%Y%m%d') < CURDATE() - INTERVAL 14 DAY
)
GROUP BY SYSTEMS.Sid 

UNION ALL

SELECT
  systems.sid, systems.Name, systems.checkdate,
  count(approved) as MissingPatches
FROM (
  patches LEFT JOIN Systems
  ON Systems.Sid = patches.Sid
)
WHERE patches.Approved = 1
  AND patches.Installed = 0
  AND Patches.Sid = systems.Sid
GROUP BY patches.Sid
HAVING COUNT(approved) > 0
ORDER BY Sid
```

---

#### RESULTS:

```
+-----+-----------+-----------+----------------+  
| sid |   Name    | checkdate | MissingPatches |  
+-----+-----------+-----------+----------------+  
|  79 | WCLVS001  |         0 |              0 |   
| 112 | TAR201    |         0 |              0 |  
| 112 | TAR201    |         0 |              3 |  
| 179 | DOX109N   |  20130603 |              0 |  
| 181 | DOX122T   |  20130520 |              0 |  
| 184 | DOX121T   |  20130411 |              0 |  
| 248 | ROW1767L  |  20130530 |              0 |  
| 248 | ROW1767L  |  20130530 |              2 |  
| 251 | ROW1765L  |  20130528 |              0 |  
| 251 | ROW1765L  |  20130528 |              1 |  
| 268 | GWR-LAP16 |  20130531 |              0 |  
| 268 | GWR-LAP16 |  20130531 |              3 |  
| 278 | ROW1522L  |  20130420 |              0 |  
| 278 | ROW1522L  |  20130420 |              1 |  
| 281 | ROW255L   |  20130509 |              0 |  
| 281 | ROW255L   |  20130509 |              1 |  
| 283 | GWR-LAP03 |  20130413 |              0 |  
| 283 | GWR-LAP03 |  20130413 |              2 |  
| 313 | GMSRT     |  20130623 |              1 |  
| 334 | ROW1517L  |  20130523 |              0 |  
| 335 | ROW1792L  |         0 |              0 |  
| 335 | ROW1792L  |         0 |             23 |  
| 339 | TEXCE-PC  |         0 |              0 |  
+-----+-----------+-----------+----------------+
```

Comment: Can you explain what you would like the results to look like?  Perhaps post a listing.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear.  If you look at the last table, (results), you'll see duplicate SID and NAME items in some cases, one will have a zero under missing patches, the other the true number of missing patches.  What I'm trying to get to is a single line for each system, showing only a missing patches number from zero to whatever the actual count is.  In this case for example, SID 112 would have the one line with the number missing as 3.  (I see that in my trim for this example, the very first line is confusing, it should have a duplicate with zero missingpatches number, my apologies).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sure there is a better way to do this, but I think this will give you what you are looking for.  Simply put your `UNION` query as a sub-select, and then `SUM` the MissingPatches column.

```
SELECT s.id, Name, checkdate, SUM(MissingPatches) as MissingPatches

FROM

(

Select systems.sid,systems.Name,systems.checkdate ,SUM(0) as MissingPatches 
from (patches left JOIN Systems ON Systems.Sid=patches.Sid) 
where (STR_TO_DATE(systems.checkdate, '%Y%m%d') < CURDATE() - INTERVAL 14 DAY) 
Group by SYSTEMS.Sid

Union All

Select systems.sid,systems.Name,systems. checkdate ,count(approved) as MissingPatches
from (patches left JOIN Systems ON Systems.Sid=patches.Sid) 
where patches.Approved = 1 and patches.Installed = 0 and Patches.Sid = systems.Sid
group by patches.Sid having count(approved) > 0

) as x

GROUP BY s.id, Name, checkdate
```

Comment: I think that's got it.  I've never used subs before, so this is new to me.  I presume that to add additional counts, those would also be subs?  This takes me miles, thanks!

Comment: Your fix worked flawlessly.  I've moved on and encountered another issue, which seems to be pretty common, but I'm not finding a fix.

Comment: In a third table, "locations", there is also a column named "NAME", which I need to show in the query results if at all possible.  I am joining that table with  " LEFT JOIN Clients ON Clients.ClientID=Computers.clientid "  When I try to add it, whether or not I specify the table names, I get a 1060 "Duplicate Column Name 'Name' " error.  I know duplicate column names are a pain for sub-queries, but this is a canned package, so I can't change the back end.  Am I out of luck?  Thanks again!